# Local file server needs root access to change permissions

Tags: linux, freebsd, root, truenas

The previous developers set up a local Linux file server (FreeNAS 8.1) and while we can log in through the username they provided we do not have root access so we can not change permissions or do anything outside of the user they gave us. Is there some way to reset the root password through a reboot or USB drive or something? I'm reluctant to crack it but if there's a safe way to do this without compromising the data then I would be OK with it.

Comment: Freenas isn't Linux - it's FreeBSD btw.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boot CD. See the guide provided [here](http://www.marksanborn.net/linux/recovering-from-a-lost-linux-root-password/).